# What type of algorithm should i use?

Tags: algorithm, graph, nodes

Lets say I have four group

> A [ 0, 4, 9]
>
> B [ 2, 6, 11]
>
> C [ 3, 8, 13]
>
> D [ 7, 12 ]

Now I need one number from each group(i.e a new group) E [num of A,num of B, num of C, num of D], such that the difference between the maximum num in E and minimum num in E should be possible lowest.What type of problem is this ? which graph algorithm will be better to solve this kind of problem ?
Thanks in advance.

P.S : I'm trying to solve this in java and sorry for the unspecified title.

Edit :
Finally I've found what I'm actually looking for http://rcrezende.blogspot.in/2010/08/smallest-relevant-text-snippet-for.html

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the tag.

Comment: @Baz not a homework I'm in middle of a project where I have this situation.

Comment: if you take the minimum of each group , it should work ?

Comment: @RedhopIT Consider A [0, 10000] B [100, 9999] C [200, 9998] D [300, 9997]. Taking the minimum of each group would not work in this case.

Comment: Would this question be better at http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Pigueiras: Questions about algorithms are on topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @RedhopIT nope. then the difference between the max and min of final group[0,2,3,7] would be 7 - 0 = 7 which is higher than group[9,6,8,7] with diff is 9 - 7 = 2

Comment: @Pigueiras is there a stack site for algorithm ??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath sorry for mistake yeah its 9 - 6 = 3

Comment: Are the numbers picked from each group picked randomly?

Comment: Is this optimal? Sort each of the groups. Start at index 0 for each sorted group, then increment the index that has the smallest value. Calculate the difference of group E (formed by those indices) at each iteration.

Comment: @irrelephant I dont understand. Can you be more specific.

Comment: Don't know if this'll work, but you have indexA, indexB, ...C, and ...D. Form group E with values at A[indexA], ... . While the difference of group E is greater than 3, increment the index which refers to the lowest value. Check the difference of group E at each step of the loop. Edit, I guess this won't work if the groups don't have unique values. =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Combine contents of every group into a single array. Each element of the array should be a pair of (number, group name).
2. Sort this array by numbers.
3. Advance two iterators, one after another. Move first iterator when elements of not every group are between these iterators. Move second iterator when there is an element of each group between these iterators. For details see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9775301/1009831).
4. Minimum distance between iterators determine optimal resulting group (you only need to drop unneeded elements when there are several representatives of the same group there).

---

Other algorithm:

1. Sort elements of each group (if not sorted already).
2. Put a pair (number, group name) for smallest elements of each group into priority queue (min-heap, priority=number).
3. Remove smallest element from the queue and replace it with the next element from the same group.
4. Repeat step 3 until no more elements are left in some group. Calculate max(queue) - min(queue) for each iteration and if it is smaller than any previous value, update the best-so-far resulting group.

Comment: The problem is indeed mappable (group is analogy to the distinct characters in the alphabet, number is more or less analogy to the position of the character in the text). +1

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do an exhaustive search, with quick termination, it's not as bad as it seems.

For example if you pick a number from A and B, you can pick two numbers from C which are the closest to those two numbers, using any other number cannot yield better results.

- For each element of A: call it `a`, you are looking for a numbers which are close to interval (a,a)
- Now for each group pick the closest numbers (you can do it with binary search). Now you have a new search interval, either (a,b1) or (b2,a)

Example:

- Pick 4 from A, searching close to (4,4)
- A) Pick 2 from B, searching close to (2,4)
- .... Pick 3 from C, it's in the interval. searching close to (2,4)
- .... Pick 7 from D, interval is (2,7), distance is 5.
- B) Pick 6 from B, searching close to (4,6)
- ....